# Unable to Redirect URL after JQuery Ajax PUT Request

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, node.js, express

I am having issues with a put request that seems to hang on the client side. The PUT request successfully updates the data on the server side, but it does not do anything else within a  `$.ajax().done()` function nor in a `success: function(result){}` function.

The `$('#update').click(function (){}` is supposed to get the `name` and `description` inputs from the HTML front end, utilize the `$.ajax()` function to submit the put request, utilize the `router.put()` to submit the data to the `controller`

I think I'm missing something small but crucial. any assistance is appreciated. thank you!

## HTML

```
<h1>Project Details</h1>

<div class="input-group mb-3">
  <span class="input-group-text" id="inputGroup-sizing-default">ID</span>
  <input
    type="text"
    class="form-control"
    name="id"
    aria-label="Sizing example input"
    aria-describedby="inputGroup-sizing-default"
    value="<%= project.id %>"
    disabled
  />
</div>

<div class="input-group mb-3">
  <span class="input-group-text" id="inputGroup-sizing-default">Created Date</span>
  <input
    type="text"
    class="form-control"
    name="createdDate"
    aria-label="Sizing example input"
    aria-describedby="inputGroup-sizing-default"
    value="<%= project.createdDate %>"
    disabled
  />
</div>

<div class="input-group mb-3">
  <span class="input-group-text" id="inputGroup-sizing-default">Last Updated Date</span>
  <input
    type="text"
    class="form-control"
    name="lastUpdated"
    aria-label="Sizing example input"
    aria-describedby="inputGroup-sizing-default"
    value="<%= project.lastUpdated %>"
    disabled
  />
</div>

<div class="input-group mb-3">
  <span class="input-group-text" id="inputGroup-sizing-default">Project Name</span>
  <input
    id="name"
    type="text"
    class="form-control"
    name="name"
    aria-label="Sizing example input"
    aria-describedby="inputGroup-sizing-default"
    value="<%= project.name %>"
  />
</div>

<div class="input-group mb-3">
  <span class="input-group-text" id="inputGroup-sizing-default">Description</span>
  <input
    id="description"
    type="text"
    class="form-control"
    name="description"
    aria-label="Sizing example input"
    aria-describedby="inputGroup-sizing-default"
    value="<%= project.description %>"
  />
</div>

<button id="delete" type="delete" class="btn btn-danger">DELETE</button>
<a type="cancel" class="btn btn-secondary" href="/projects">Cancel</a>
<button id="update" class="btn btn-primary float-right">Update</button>

<script>
  $(document).ready(function () {
    $('#update').click(function () {
      var settings = {
        url: 'http://localhost:3000/projects/<%= project.id %>',
        method: 'PUT',
        dataType: 'json',
        data: { name: $('#name').val(), description: $('#description').val() },
        success: function (result) {
          console.log(result);
        },
      };
      $.ajax(settings);
    });

    $('#delete').click(function () {
      var settings = {
        url: 'http://localhost:3000/projects/<%= project.id %>',
        method: 'DELETE',
        timeout: 0,
        success: function (response) {
          console.log(response);
        },
      };

      $.ajax(settings);
    });
  });
</script>
```

## Expressjs Router

```
const express = require('express');
const ProjectModel = require('../src/controller/projectController');
const router = express.Router();
const controller = new ProjectModel();

module.exports = (params) => {
  const { projectService } = params;

  // UPDATE
  router.put('/:id', async (request, response) => {
    await controller.updateById(request);
    return response.redirect("/projects");
  });

  return router;
};
```

## Mongoose MongoDB Controller

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const projectModel = require('../model/projectModel');

const { ProjectSchema } = require('../model/projectModel');

const Project = mongoose.model('projects', ProjectSchema);

class ProjectModel {
  constructor() {
    this.Project = Project;
  }


  async updateById(request) {
    const { name, description } = request.body;
    const { id } = request.params;
    const query = { _id: request.params.id };
    const options = { new: true };
    const update = { name: name, description: description, lastUpdated: Date.now() };
    let result = await this.Project.findByIdAndUpdate(query, { $set: update }, options);
    console.log(result);
  }

}

module.exports = ProjectModel;
```

Comment: Use window location reload in succession

Comment: nothing seems to run in the success, no `console.log()` statements run either.

Comment: Than you should check controller side ör midlayer which handling your jquery request

Answer (score 1):

I needed to put the 303 status code in the `return response.redirect();`. Without the 303 status code the ajax success was never ran.

```
  router.put('/:id', async (request, response) => {
    await controller.updateById(request);
    return response.redirect(303, "/projects");
  });
```